# '[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/.wdm'.' When using selenium on ec2

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, amazon-ec2, selenium-chromedriver

Here is my selenium code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get(url)
elem1 = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "location_value")
elem2 = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "q")
elem1.click()
elem1.clear()
elem1.send_keys(city)
elem2.click()
elem2.clear()
elem2.send_keys(category)
elem2.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "location_google_maps_homepage"))).click()
url = driver.current_url
driver.close()
```

This all works great locally in my pycharm, then when i move it to my ec2 instance i get this error `[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/.wdm'`. I have cromedriver downloaded in my ec2 and stored at `/usr/bin/chromedriver`.
What do I need to do to fix this?